# parsing this JSON

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse this JSONbut it does not have the array with respect i will get the count.

As I used to parse
if the JSONwill be:

```
{
    "earthquakes": [
        {
            "eqid": "c0001xgp",
            "magnitude": 8.8,
            "lng": 142.369,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
            "depth": 24.4,
            "lat": 38.322
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2007hear",
            "magnitude": 8.4,
            "lng": 101.3815,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2007-09-12 09:10:26",
            "depth": 30,
            "lat": -4.5172
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2007aqbk",
            "magnitude": 8,
            "lng": 156.9567,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2007-04-01 18:39:56",
            "depth": 10,
            "lat": -8.4528
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2007hec6",
            "magnitude": 7.8,
            "lng": 100.9638,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2007-09-12 21:49:01",
            "depth": 10,
            "lat": -2.5265
        },
        {
            "eqid": "a00043nx",
            "magnitude": 7.7,
            "lng": 100.1139,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2010-10-25 12:42:22",
            "depth": 20.6,
            "lat": -3.4841
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2010utc5",
            "magnitude": 7.7,
            "lng": 97.1315,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2010-04-06 20:15:02",
            "depth": 31,
            "lat": 2.3602
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2009mebz",
            "magnitude": 7.6,
            "lng": 99.9606,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2009-09-30 08:16:09",
            "depth": 80,
            "lat": -0.7889
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2009kdb2",
            "magnitude": 7.6,
            "lng": 92.9226,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2009-08-10 17:55:39",
            "depth": 33.1,
            "lat": 14.0129
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2010zbca",
            "magnitude": 7.6,
            "lng": 123.533,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2010-07-23 20:51:11",
            "depth": 576.3,
            "lat": 6.4939
        },
        {
            "eqid": "2010xkbv",
            "magnitude": 7.5,
            "lng": 91.9379,
            "src": "us",
            "datetime": "2010-06-12 17:26:50",
            "depth": 35,
            "lat": 7.7477
        }
    ]
}
```

The code:

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("url");
JSONArray  earthquake= json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");
```

but i have got this type

```
[
    {
        "id": "4",
        "head": "gggg",
        "details": "gdhghfhgfh",
        "d2": "jkjkjk",
        "datetime": "2012-03-12",
        "last_update": "2012-03-14 05:08:32"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "head": "bb1",
        "details": "sddassa",
        "d2": "ddsdsddsd",
        "datetime": "0000-00-00",
        "last_update": "2012-03-13 07:33:56"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "head": "hhh",
        "details": "hhhh",
        "d2": "dsdsdds",
        "datetime": "2012-03-01",
        "last_update": "2012-03-12 08:35:27"
    }
]
```

there is nothing like "earthquake" in previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly convert server response is an array of data, then you can directly convert it into JSONArray using `JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(stringResponse);`

If you get JSON response in string then you can convert it into JSONArray as follows

```
        String stringResponse = JSONfunctions.getJSONResponsefromURL("url");
        try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(stringResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Sure, because you asked for the JSON array of the key "earthquake" and now you got the JSON array matching the key "earthquake".</strike>

Just now I understood your question. It is unlikely that the JSON library will change the content, it is more likely that the content retrieved from the url is a bit different each time. To make sure that this is the case, try this code:

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("url");
Log.d("Some tag", json.toString());
JSONArray  earthquake= json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");
Log.d("Some tag", earthquake.toString());
```

Comment: but if you look at the json string closely, you'll find anomalies